# Spring JPA обновлять сущность при нарушении уникальности вторичного ключа

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

Мой микросервис должен уметь сохранять емейлы и при этом не создавать дубликатов. Вот так быть не должно:

```
"emails": [
        {
          "type": "CLAIMS",
          "email": "test@mail.com"
        },
        {
          "type": "CLAIMS",
          "email": "test@mail.com"
        },
        {
          "type": "CLAIMS",
          "email": "test@mail.com"
        },
        {
          "type": "CLAIMS",
          "email": "test@mail.com"
        }
      ]
```

Как можно запретить создавать дубликаты и при этом не падать с ошибкой? В SQLite есть отличный запрос `insert or update`, который при нарушении констрекнта делает `update`. Как то же самое сделать в `PostgreSQL`?

Я использую `Spring Boot JPA`, поэтому предполагаю, что при создании констрейнта надо будет разметить энтити дпоолнительынми аннотациями. Какие аннотации для этого есть?

Сущность `Email` связана с сущностью `Organization` связью @OneToMany: одна организация может иметь несколько емейлов. Емейлы можно редактировать и добавлять.

Comment: сделать сначала проверку на этот email есть ил он в бд или нет.

Comment: вы определитесь, где вам нужно решение на стороне SQL именно для Postgrsql или на стороне Java

Comment: @Tsyklop, долго

Comment: @Komdosh, скорее всего, на стороне java, чтобы не привязываться жестко к бд. Мне интересно узнать оба варианта.

Comment: если `Email` хранятся в отдельной таблице, не лучше ли все прочитать, объединить массивы, и заново все сохранить?

Answer (score 1):

Как насчет такого решение. Посмотрите, может сработает.

```java
public interface EntityRepository extends CrudRepository<Entity, Integer> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "INSERT INTO entity (name, age) VALUES(?1,?2) " +
                       "ON CONFLICT(name) DO UPDATE SET name=?1,age=?2 " +
                       "RETURNING id", nativeQuery = true)
    Integer upsert(String name, int age); 
}
```

Comment: если не сработает, напишите, удалю ответ :)

Comment: Не удаляйте ответ, я хочу разобраться в этом запросе. Однако запрос не к моей задаче. У меня к Entity (емейлы) идет связь @OneToMany от главной сущности. То есть, для главной сущности можно задать несколько емейлов

Comment: @typemoon у меня просто нет возможности проверить работоспособность данного кода, по этому не могу быть точно уверен, что он с работает. Но исходя из документации https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html должно сработать, если есть уникальный ключ.

Но так как у вас таблица друга, мне кажется вам нужно вопрос дополнить, так думаю будет легче дать правильный ответ.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.